# PHP oop build array

Tags: php, oop

If I would need to build up an array with OOP based PHP, would this be the proper way to do it?

```
class MyClass {

    $array = array();

    function addElement($value) {
        $this->array[] = $value;

    }

    function fetch() {

        $return = $this->memcached->getMulti($this->array);        

        return $return;
    }


}
```

PHP file where it will be used:

```
<?php

$this->myClass->addElement('key1');
$this->myClass->addElement('key1');
$this->myClass->addElement('key1');
$var = $this->myClass->fetch();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion: use SPL [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) instead of implementing your own solution.

Comment: It looks clean in the documention, but I am guessing that I cannot get a clean array back from it instead of the array it returns by default?

Comment: You can get the plain array version of it with ArrayObject::getArrayCopy() http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php

Comment: Fantastic, I know that there was a solution out there!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface

Comment: Out of interest *why* can't you use it? The `ArrayObject` solution above means you would be.